# CallbackOnCollectedDelegate error when using OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, openfiledialog

I would like to add an OpenFileDialog to my application. The dialog opens as expected but as soon as I close the dialog I get an error regarding "CallbackOnCollectedDelegate". I looked for OpenFileDialog examples on the web but they do not look much different from my code. Also I looked at solutions for the "CallbackOnCollectedDelegate" error here on stackoverflow but unfortunately I do not see the point where my code fails. 
I am using a similar constructions to open other self created dialog boxes in my program - without problems. This is the first time I try to use a predefined Dialog and maybe I am doing something strange here?

```
OpenFileDialog Dialog_OpenFile;

private void OpenFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //open file
{
  if (Dialog_OpenFile == null) //only create once
    {
        Dialog_OpenFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        Dialog_OpenFile.InitialDirectory = ".";
        Dialog_OpenFile.RestoreDirectory = false;
        Dialog_OpenFile.Multiselect = false;
        Dialog_OpenFile.Filter = "OpenOffice (*.ods)|*.ods|Microsoft Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        Dialog_OpenFile.FilterIndex = 2; 
    }

    DialogResult status = Dialog_OpenFile.ShowDialog();
    if (status == DialogResult.OK) { ...do something... }
}
```

I have added the error message I get (unfortunately in German but the most important parts should be understandable):

> Der Assistent für verwaltetes Debugging
>   ""CallbackOnCollectedDelegate"" hat ein Problem in
>   ""C:\Users...\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\myprog\myprog\bin\Debug\myprog.vshost.exe""
>   festgestellt. Zusätzliche Informationen: Für den von der Garbage
>   Collection gesammelten Delegaten vom Typ
>   "System.Windows.Forms!System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods+WndProc::Invoke"
>   wurde ein Rückruf durchgeführt. Dies kann Anwendungsabstürze,
>   Datenbeschädigung und -verlust zur Folge haben. Beim Übergeben von
>   Delegaten an nicht verwalteten Code müssen die Delegaten von der
>   verwalteten Anwendung beibehalten werden, bis sichergestellt ist, dass
>   sie nie aufgerufen werden.
>
> Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "System.NullReferenceException" ist in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll aufgetreten. Zusätzliche Informationen: Der
>   Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
>
> "myprog.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: myprog.vshost.exe):
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
>   geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist
>   optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert. Das
>   Programm "[3452] myprog.vshost.exe" wurde mit Code 0 (0x0) beendet.

Comment: What is `CallbackOnCollectedDelegate`? When do you use it? don't see it used anywhere in your code.

Comment: No, CallbackOnCollectedDelegate is part of the error message I get: "Der Assistent für verwaltetes Debugging ""CallbackOnCollectedDelegate"" hat ein Problem in ""C:\...\myprog.vshost.exe"" festgestellt.
Zusätzliche Informationen: Für den von der Garbage Collection gesammelten Delegaten vom Typ "System.Windows.Forms!System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods+WndProc::Invoke" wurde ein Rückruf durchgeführt. Dies kann Anwendungsabstürze, Datenbeschädigung und -verlust zur Folge haben..."

Comment: It is likely to be a bad shell extension, written in .NET.  You are getting to debug it as well :)  Get rid of it.

Comment: The following files are loaded at Startup:

Comment: The following files are loaded at Startup: LuaInterface.dll, KopiLua.dll, Accessibility.dll, myprog.resources.dll, System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll, mscorlib.resources.dll. I will look for shell extensions soon.